# Specific query to select all rows in Table A that don't match criteria defined in rows of Table B?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having trouble building a specific query to select records.  Here is a dumbed down example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Let's say I have a table called `Criteria` that looks something like this:

```
ID   Unit      Product   Part
==   ========  =======   ========
1    'sports'  'bike'    'handle'
2    'sports'  ' '       ' '
3    'furn'    'couch'   ' '
etc.
```

And I have a table called `Entries` that looks something like this:

```
ID   Tuple
==   =========================
1    'sports / bike / seat'
2    'sports / racket / frame'
3    'furn / desk / leg'
4    'furn / lamp / shade'
etc.
```

Record 1 in `Criteria` suggests that any tuple that is "sports / bike / handle" qualifies.  Record 2 in `Criteria`, where the `Product` and `Part` contain spaces, suggests that any tuple beginning with 'sports' qualifies ("sports / % / %").  Record 3 suggests that any tuple beginning with 'furn' and 'couch' qualifies ("furn / couch / %").  I want to select all the records that **don't** qualify for any of the criteria.

In this case, records 3 and 4 from `Entries` should be returned, because they don't match any of the given criteria.

I'm new to SQL, so I'm having trouble coming up with a suitable query.  My thought process is along these lines:

For each record of `Criteria`, build a string comparison string based on the `Unit`, `Product`, and `Part`.  For record 1, for example, the string would be *'sports / bike / handle'.*  For record 2, the string would be *'sports / % / %'*, and for record 3: *'furn / couch / %'*.  Now, select all records where `Tuple` does not equal any of those strings.  I'm having trouble translating this into SQL terms, and that is where I need your help.

Comment: Sorry to say it but I would consider redesign the tables instead trying to make it work!

Comment: Why are you storing tuples inside columns inside real tuples (rows)?? Make the 3 values 3 columns!

Comment: Lol, I knew you guys would freak out.  I did too when I first got this project.  The tuples are stored as strings because they come from somewhere else.  It's unfortunate and annoying, but that much can't be changed at this point.  It's difficult to explain without giving away details I shouldn't :P

Comment: You'll have to split the tuple to do anything useful with it anyway. So why not split it before storage instead of after?

Comment: Well, first of all what I've shown in my question is only an example tuple.  The way it was actually being used up until now did not demand that it be split.  This NEW project that I'm working on does something special with the tuples that had not been anticipated.  That's all I can say.  The example I've given is intentionally a bit misleading in order to be safe as possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you storing data like that? Inquiring minds want to know.

However, you might try something along these lines:

```
select *
from entries e
where not exists ( select *
                   from criteria c
                   where e.tuple like           case coalesce( unit    , '' ) when '' then '%' else unit    end
                                      + ' / ' + case coalesce( product , '' ) when '' then '%' else product end
                                      + ' / ' + case coalesce( part    , '' ) when '' then '%' else part    end
                 )
```

Ugly, but gits 'er done.

Comment: The data wasn't originally meant to be parsed and separated - it was simply a single identifying string.  It's only now that they would like to use it in a different way.  Hmm, I'll check your solution out tomorrow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an outer join, using like:

```
select e.*
from Entries e left outer join
     (select c.*,
             ((case when c.unit = ' ' then '%' else c.unit end) + ' / ' +
              (case when c.product = ' ' then '%' else c.product end) + ' / ' +
              (case when c.part = ' ' then '%' else c.part end)
             ) as likestr
      from Criteria c
     ) c
     on e.tuple like likestr
where c.id is null
```

This will be an expensive operation, but should do what you want.

The data structure would make more sense if you stored the components of the tuple in separate columns.  Then you could do a column-by-column comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will try this tomorrow.  (Yeah, I WISH they were stored column by column!)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work.  There was a syntax error and I couldn't figure out where.

Comment: @Dalal: Perhaps it was a missing comma just after `c.*` (now fixed).